# How to create a SharedWorker using a blob?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I would like to create a SharedWorker as described in a chapter of an excellent book: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch5.md

I was able to cook up a very good example for *normal* web workers:

```
function createAsker(limit) {
    var blob = new Blob(["onmessage = function(e) { " +
                           "if (self.higher === undefined) self.higher = " + limit + "; " +
                           "if (self.lower === undefined) self.lower = 1;" +
                           "if (e.data === 'correct') { " +
                             "postMessage('Party time'); " +
                           "} else {" +
                             "if (e.data === 'greater') self.lower = parseInt((self.lower + self.higher) / 2);" +
                             "if (e.data === 'lower') self.higher = parseInt((self.lower + self.higher) / 2);" +
                             "postMessage(parseInt((self.lower + self.higher) / 2));" +
                           "}" +
                         "}"]);
    var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var worker = new Worker(blobURL);
    return worker;
}

var asker = createAsker(1000);

function createAnswerer(limit) {
    var blob = new Blob(["onmessage = function(e) { " +
                            "postMessage((e.data == " + limit + ") ? 'correct' : ((e.data < " + limit + ") ? 'greater' : 'lower'));" +
                         "}"]);
    var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var worker = new Worker(blobURL);
    return worker;
}

var answerer = createAnswerer(42);

asker.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Asker says: ' + e.data);
  if (e.data !== "Party time") {
    setTimeout(function() {answerer.postMessage(e.data)}, 1000);
  }
};

answerer.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Answerer says: ' + e.data);
  setTimeout(function() {asker.postMessage(e.data)}, 1000);
};

asker.postMessage('start');
```

Yet, I have difficulty on creating a shared worker. I attempted to create one with this code:

```
function createWorker() {
    var blob = new Blob(['addEventListener( "connect", function(evt){ ' +
                            'var port = evt.ports[0]; ' +
                            'port.addEventListener( "message", function(evt){' +
                              'port.postMessage( .. );debugger;' +
                            '} );' +
                            'port.start();' +
                          '} );']);
    var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var w = new SharedWorker(blobURL);
    return w;
}

var w = createWorker();

w.port.start();

w.port.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log(e.data);
};

w.port.onmessage('foobar');
```

and after sending the message of foobar I would expect my shared worker to post a message, or at least I expect to be guided into the code by the debugger, yet, when I run this code the console gives two undefined as a response.

Comment: I don't think you can make a `SharedWorker` from a `Blob` as every `Blob` has a different Object URL and can hardly be shared.

Comment: @Bergi interesting point. The shared worker was created however, in Chrome. I'm not saying everything is correct, I would not have a question if everything would have gone as expected. However, if we put aside the way the sharedworker is being created, do you see any other problems in this code either in the script passed to the Blob constructor or in the usage just after the function?

Comment: `w.port.onmessage('foobar');`  looks definitely wrong. You don't want to invoke the event handler directly. (If you had used `w.port.addEventListener("message", function(e) { console.log(e.data); });` it would have led to an obvious error message). You probably want to use `postMessage` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base64 encoding gives a permanent URL until the source code changes.

```js
const source = 'importScript("https://anotherhost/worker.js")';
const url = 'data:application/javascript;base64,' + btoa(source);
const worker = new SharedWorker(url);
```

It works at least in Chrome 73 and Firefox 66.

There is a [limit to the length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs#Common_problems) of the encoded URL of about 65 kilobytes.

Comment: You could probably get around that length limit by first creating a smaller or minimal `SharedWorker`, and then having it request rest of the code it needs from the first window it gets connected to, via `PostMessage()`.  Once received it would then have to `eval()` this into its own global scope.  ([And note that there's a little trick to getting eval() to work in global scope...](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/)).

Comment: A small fix to the accepted answer. It should be `importScripts` not `importScript`. `const source = 'importScripts("https://anotherhost/worker.js")';`